# how to call async task after getting gcm id in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have a broadcast receiver which is used for gcm registration. now i want to store the gcm id in a remote database. for that, i need to execute an async task to make the call to a script to do the same. how can i do that?

i have tried calling another activity from the broadcast receiver, but the async task to update on db does not work.

```
//File: BroadcastReceiver.java
public class BroadcastReceiver{
    //Code to get GCM ID
}

//File: MyActivity.java

public class MyActivity{
   //Want to log GCM Id here
}
```

Comment: Where do you have your AsyncTask?. It should be as easy as new MyAsyncTask().execute(), if you have MyAsyncTask in the same .java

Comment: what does it mean by does not work? post your async task if you want others here to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "remote database"? Any reason you need to use an AsyncTask instead of spawning a simple thread?

Comment: the database is present on a webhost. as its an http post request to add gcm id to db,, i am using an async task

Comment: Then spawn a simple thread, no need to use AsyncTask unless you have a particular reason to do so.